# App remove due to Violation of the Permissions policy

Tags: android, publishing, google-play-console

My app was removed due to Violation of the Permissions policy, we have uploaded new build with fixes but its not publish till now , approx 6 hours gone.Please provide solution if any one face this issue on play console.

Comment: Are you reading or sending data to phone number And if that is read this article <H>https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/permissions/<?H>

Comment: It will take some time around 24 hours

Comment: @rajkavadia we remove all permission regarding sms and call and upload build but its not reflected till now approx 7 hours completed.

Comment: @MD Can send me any link where we found, It will take 24 hours

Comment: There is no link exist. It was my own experience. @ThakurAnoopSingh

Answer (score 0):

You should post what was your violation policy sent by google in your email. It mostly due to google policy change in their security. you should check your android permission and follow it properly.

Comment: We updated accordingly google policy change and new build uploaded but its not reflected approx 7 hours completed.

Comment: no its showing removed and not getting any alert after upload new build.

Comment: try to upload it again if you can just change the app id of the app. I got the same problem recently.

Comment: we uploaded again same before 2 hours but not reflecting till now.